# Check multiple path with Test-path

Tags: powershell

In my function i have 3 no mandatory and no positional parameters `Folder1, Folder2 and Folder3`, before running my function i would like to check for each selected parameter if folder exist. It must be something dynamic because user can specify randomly one or two or all tree folders.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass an array to Test-Path

```
Test-Path c:, d:, e:
True
True
True
```

**EDIT**

So I believe from your comment that you have something like this:

```
$mypaths = "c:","d:",$null
Test-Path $mypaths
```

Which issues the following error:

```
Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

Then you can try this:

```
$mypaths = "c:","d:",$null
$mypaths | Foreach { if ($_){Test-Path $_}}
```

Which results in only two valid paths.

So you could consider checking the returned values:

```
$valid = $mypaths | Foreach { if ($_){Test-Path $_}}

write-host "Variable `$mypaths contains $($mypaths.count) paths, and $($valid.count) were found valid"
```

Which outputs:

```
Variable $mypaths contains 3 paths, and 2 were found valid
```

Comment: Hello Micky, i get a error when i use your solution `Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string`

Comment: Did you try my solution as is or with some other variables?

Comment: This solution work only if three variables are $true, but as i said it must be dynamic, function parameter can be entered or not.

Comment: I think the more idiomatic way to write it would be `$valid = $mypaths | where {$_ -and (Test-Path $_)}`.