# Search for a file, across multiple volumes

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I had recently, come across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072620/check-multiple-path-with-test-path) but it's old and I figured ya'all would want me to start a new thread.

Basically, I'm writing a PS script for deploying WIMs.  We **map a UNC path as a mapped drive** and then run a batch file that searches for specific files and creates a variable based on their paths.  Once the variable is in place, the script continues - using said variable.  A sample of the code in the batch file looks like this:

```
FOR %%i IN (D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO IF EXIST %%i:\Win10.wim SET _WIMLocation=%%i:
```

How does one duplicate something like that within PS?  Normally, I'd hard-code the drive letter but if someone else maps a drive with a different letter, the script breaks.  So, that's why it searches through the drive letters...

Comment: Unlike other sites SO prefers not to create a new thread if something answers your question already. That said there was enough different for a separate question. e.g. You wanted to save a new variable and the array did not include the `:` which has a tricky issue then since `:` is the used for scopes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's is one way to do that in PowerShell:

First you will make an Array with the Drive letters. By wrapping in either quotes or double quotes each letter will be a string and then use commas to separate each value so that the variable will be an array of strings.

```
$Drives = "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
```

Then use a `foreach` loop, which loops through each value of the array.

```
foreach ($Drive in $Drives) {
```

Then use an `if` statement for the test, and inside the `if` you can test if a folder or file exists with the `Test-Path` cmdlet. The `${}` is so that I can put the variable inside the quotes and have it all be one string, without the parser getting confused by the `:`. Alternatively you could build the path with concatenation `Test-Path $($Drive + ":\win10.wim")` Where `$()` is a sub-expression to be evaluated first and then the `+` operator will concat the two strings.

```
   if (Test-Path "${Drive}:\Win10.wim") {
```

Finally you can set a variable to equal to the `$Drive` variable when the `if` statement succeeds

```
       $WIMLocation = $Drive
   }
}
```

Here's what it looks like altogether:

```
$Drives = "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"
foreach ($Drive in $Drives) {
   if (Test-Path "${Drive}:\Win10.wim") {
       $WIMLocation = $Drive
   }
}
```

Comment: One issue that I ran into and others may as well...  I had a PS session opened as "admin" and that one did not see the mapped drive.  However, when I opened a new session normally and ran the same code, it saw the path just fine!  This will run in WinPE, as we are deploying WIMs with it so, I'm hoping we won't run into this issue.

Comment: [This is the fix to that](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to search just local volumes, not network drives, you'd enumerate the drives using [`Get-Volume`](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/storage/get-volume):

```
Get-Volume | Where-Object {
    $_.DriveType -eq 'Fixed' -and
    $_.DriveLetter
} | Select-Object -Expand DriveLetter
```

or (on older Windows/PowerShell versions) query the [`Win32_Volume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515.aspx) WMI class:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | Where-Object {
    $_.DriveType -eq 3 -and
    $_.DriveLetter
} | Select-Object -Expand DriveLetter
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find all the active FileSystem drive on a system you can use :

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Answer (score 2):

This will duplicate your batch script. Note you don't have to hard code the drive letters here.

```
$drives = Get-PSDrive | ? {$_.Provider.Name -eq "FileSystem" }

foreach ($drive in  $drives) {

   $path = $drive.Name + ":\Win10.wim"

   if (Test-Path $path) {
       [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("_WIMLocation", $drive.Name, "User")
   }
}
```

You can substitute

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("_WIMLocation", $drive, "User")
```

with

```
$env:_WIMLocation = $drive.name
```

if you don't need the environment variable to persist