# IF (Test-Path $Path) - Detect 2 files at once?

Tags: powershell

I am using the code below to test if a file exists or not but I need it to verify 2 files. Is there a way to do that using my code below to detect the presence of 2 files? Would something like this work?

```
If (Test-Path $appPath) AND (Test-Path $appPath2)
```

Original:

```
Function CurrentUser{
$loggedInUserName = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | select username
$loggedInUserName = [string]$loggedInUserName
$loggedinUsername = $loggedInUserName.Split("=")
$loggedInUserName = $loggedInUserName[1]
$loggedInUserName = $loggedInUserName.Split("}")
$loggedInUserName = $loggedInUserName[0]
$loggedInUserName = $loggedInUserName.Split("\")
$loggedInUserName = $loggedInUserName[1]
Return $loggedInUserName
}
$user = CurrentUser

$appPath = "C:\Users\" + $user + "\AppData\LocalLow\Test.bat"
If (Test-Path $appPath) {
    Write-Host "User Appdata detected successfully!"
}
```

Comment: If (Test-Path $appPath -and Test-Path $appPath2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check multiple path with Test-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072620/check-multiple-path-with-test-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be `if (Test-Path $appPath1 -and Test-Path $appPath2) {...`, rather than `...AND...`, but yes, PowerShell does support compound conditions. I would tend to parenthesize the individual conditions as well (`if ((Test-Path $appPath1) -and (Test-Path $appPath2)) {...`), but that’s a personal idiosyncrasy.

The standard boolean operators are `-and`, `-or`, `-xor`, and `-not`; see [`Get-Help about_Logical_Operators -full`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-6) for details.